# Error en SDL al intentar abrir un archivo con letras tildadas (como córdoba.jpg) c++

Tags: c++, csv, c++11

Estimada comunidad, hola.
Mi problema es el siguiente: con un programa que usa **SDL2** y **SDL2_Image**, el mismo abre archivos (ficheros) y luego los guarda con modificaciones.
Al intentar abrir archivos **sin tildes (áéíóú)** ni **letras 'Ñ'** (por ejemplo "*buenos aires.jpg*") funciona perfecto. Pero si hay alguna letra como las mencionadas (por ejemplo "***córdoba.jpg***"), SDL_Image genera un error de que "No pudo abrir el archivo".
Sin embargo, si uso el flujo std::ifstream con **exactamente el mismo nombre de archivo, el ifstream lo abre perfectamente**....
¿Es un error al usar caracteres latinos? ¿UNICODE, UTF, tienen algo que ver?

*Un poco más de información de entorno:* Windows 10, SDL2 y SDL2_image (últimas versiones), compilador GCC usando Mingw64 7.1.0 (versión de este año).

*Información del programa:* se usa una planilla de cálculos en CSV para obtener los nombres de los archivos (he intentado usar el CSV en vaaarias codificaciones).

Sé que tal vez estoy equivocándome en algo más profundo, pero casi agoté todas mis opciones y recurro a la comunidad.
Gracias y saludos.